# How to strictly validate XML in CXF / JAXB

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, cxf

I am sending following XML request to CXF driven REST API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <amountTransaction>
    <endUserId>tel:+912890369102</endUserId>
    <endUserId>tel:+912890369103</endUserId>
    <paymentAmount>
      <chargingInformation>
        <description>Default description</description>
      /chargingInformation>
    </paymentAmount>
</amountTransaction>
```

However my `AmountTransaction` object has `endUderId` as a `String` field. When CXF converting request into the object, it picks one of the `endUserIds` and create the object. How do I tell CXF or JAXB that throw exception if more than 1 `endUserId` elements are in XML request.

If I send the same request in JSON, it is rejected saying invalid `endUserId` element.

Answer (score 0):

CXF supports schema validation; you can configure this like so:

```
<jaxrs:server address="/"
    serviceClass="myEndpoint">
    <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
        <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:path/myschema.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    </jaxrs:schemaLocations>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I creates endpoint programatically and I set schema locations as jaxbElementProvider.setSchemaLocations(schemaLocationList);